# Group By only for some columns

Tags: sql, group-by

How do I group only some of the top selected columns in my select query?

A wrong but easy answer I would think of is this code;

```
SELECT TOP 5 brand, name, delivered, count(*)
From myTB
Where type = 'jeans'
Group By brand, name
Order By Count(*) DESC
```

The result that I'm after should return the below results;
(the above code is wrong and returns an error)

```
Brand     name       Delivered  Count
-------------------------------------
Levis     304 Slim   9/24       44
Croccer   500 Lose   3/14       22
Croccer   400 Botcut 4/7        14
Lee       Botcut 33  5/5        16
Lee       Slim 44    10/7       12
```

In the above results i get the brands together after one another even thuo the count is not decending.

I have tried and the closest that i get is with this code;

```
SELECT TOP 5 brand, name, delivered, count(*)
From myTB
Where type = 'jeans'
Group By brand, name, delivered
Order By Count(*) DESC
```

But that returns the data like this;

```
Brand     name       Delivered  Count
-------------------------------------
Levis     304 Slim   9/24       44
Croccer   500 Lose   3/14       22
Lee       Botcut 33  5/5        16
Croccer   400 Botcut 4/7        14
Lee       Slim 44    10/7       12
```

If I try to use "order by count(*), brand" i get, for some reason, the brands in descending order regardles of the count value. It seams like it only order the brand column and not both brand and count

I also tried to do a left join on the same table so that i only needed to Group By in the primary table but thats not right either and the code I come up with was really confusing so I'm going to leave that outside this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to order by the maximum count per brand first and the brand second.

```
select top 5 t1.* from (
    select brand, name, delivered, count(*)
    from myTB 
    where type = 'jeans'
    group by brand, name, delivered
) t1 join (
    select brand, cnt
    from (
        select brand, cnt,
        row_number() over (partition by brand order by cnt desc) rn
        from (select brand, count(*) cnt from myTB group by brand, name, delivered) t1
    ) t1
    where rn = 1
) t2 on t1.brand = t2.brand
order by t2.cnt desc, t2.brand
```

Comment: Spot on. This did what i was after. I did have to add a name for count(*) for it to work. ( count(*) AS numberofjeans ). Thanks alot FuzzyTree

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select TOP 5  t1.* from (SELECT brand, name, delivered, count(*)as 'test'
From myTB
Where type = 'jeans'
Group By brand, name,delivered
```

) as t1 order by t1.test desc

Comment: Tryed it but I recive the following error;
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: i edit answer try now, i put order by out of subquery